# How to sync the ANDROID DEVICE POLICY in real time when device is in KIOSK mode?

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, mdm, android-management-api, emm

I have developed my own app and set it to KIOSK as 'install_type' in Android Management API.
The problem is when device is kept to offline mode for longer time then it won't get sync with current set of policy (which is not KIOSK) even after providing internet to the device. I want it to sync at real-time and change it to current policy, i.e. exiting from KIOSK mode. I'm searching for any piece of code that can be done with my app and helps me to sync the device and exit the KIOSK mode.

Answer (score 0):

Add Play store or android device policy app in kiosk policy, so that you can be able to sync it manually.

Comment: I have tried adding android device policy app in my kiosk policy but it's not appearing in front. Will try with adding play store

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything that apps should do to trigger a policy sync. Any policy change that is applied to the device while it's offline will be picked up as soon as the device is back online. Internet connectivity is required for the device to receive any policy update.

Comment: I know it has to work like that. But the problem is I'm getting lot of issues from my support team as it is not syncing on time to many devices